# @nloops macro in Julia 0.6

Tags: julia

I'm reading the `Base.Cartesian` [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/devdocs/cartesian/#dev-cartesian-reference-1) of Julia language.

I've tried running examples provided there, for instance

```
@nloops 3 i A begin
    s += @nref 3 A i
end
```

on my Julia 0.6 installation, but none of them works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you  `using Base.Cartesian`?

Comment: oh, thanks! now it's working

Comment: @aberdysh just fyi next time it'd be great to post an error message instead of "none of them works". :)

Comment: Do keep in mind that while the `Base.Cartesian` macros still have a place, https://julialang.org/blog/2016/02/iteration is usually a much more straightforward approach.

Comment: Also be aware that you are apparently reading the docs for the latest version of Julia and not Julia 0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using Base.Cartesian`

Credit to @Gnimuc in comments (idk why people doesn't answer instead of commenting)